# Draw arrow from Open cv dense optical Flow data C#

Tags: c#, opencv, opticalflow, arrows

I want to draw arrows on my image from a dense Optical Flow data. I use OpenCVSharp.

```
public Mat GetDense(Mat nextFrameGray, Mat nextFrameColor, Mat lastgrayFrame)
        {
            Mat flow = new(lastgrayFrame.Size(), MatType.CV_32FC2);
            Cv2.CalcOpticalFlowFarneback(lastgrayFrame, nextFrameGray, flow, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0);

            return flow;
        }
```

```
            Mat denseFrame = GetDense(grayFrame, colorFrame, lastgrayFrame);

            // visualization
            Mat[] flow_parts = new Mat[2];
            Cv2.Split(denseFrame, out flow_parts);
            //Magnétude
            Mat magnitude = new Mat(), angle = new Mat(), magn_norm = new Mat();
            Cv2.CartToPolar(flow_parts[0], flow_parts[1], magnitude, angle, true);
            Cv2.Normalize(magnitude, magn_norm, 0.0, 1.0, NormTypes.MinMax);
```

I get the Mat dense frame which contains the Optical and I can't get this result...

[Result I would like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EUAW.png)

I try that and this does'nt work...

```
 for (int x = 0; x < colorFrame.Width; x+= 20)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < colorFrame.Height; y += 20)
                {
                    //Cv2.ArrowedLine(colorFrame, new Point(x, y), new Point(x+2,y+2), Scalar.Green, 2);
                    //Cv2.ArrowedLine(colorFrame, flow_parts[0].At<Point>(x,y), flow_parts[1].At<Point>(x, y), Scalar.Green, 2);
                    Debug.WriteLine(flow_parts[0].At<Point>(x, y).ToString() + " | " + flow_parts[1].At<Point>(x, y).ToString());
                }
            }
```

Is there any other way to do this ?
If not how to make this code work ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Romain! From reading, it is unclear what your problem is: Are you unable to draw arrows (how to use the UI), or can you draw arrows, but they are pointing in the wrong direction? (how to use vectors/math). You need to isolate the origin of the problem for us to help you. Can you show your result or error code?

Comment: try to make the title a specific question. It helps people with the same problem to find your question. StackOverflow is all about answer reuse.

Comment: I could not reproduce the error because I did not have data for `grayFrame` and `colorFrame` and `lastgrayFrame` in  `Mat denseFrame = GetDense(grayFrame, colorFrame, lastgrayFrame);` Please provide a tiny test-data. If we can run the code, we can't work on the problem.